# jquery update page status to server if it is active or not

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, cordova

Hi i am building a Phonegap app in which user can chat with each other and i am also sending push notification to  receiver user if he is not active in chat window. i am using Php and sending messages via ajax. i can't figured it out that how can i find if receiver is active or not. what i tried is make in new table where when user enter in chat window i update active but it fails when he closes suddenly app or navigate to some other page then it still remain active.

```
if (page.name == 'chat-window') {

   $.get('http://web.com/d/c_staus.php', {id:userid}, function (data) {

   console.log(data);

     });

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

when user navigates it to some other page, you need to check the condition everytime the page is loaded like below given example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if (page.name == 'chat-window') {
        $.get('http://web.com/d/c_staus.php', {id:userid}, function (data) {
           console.log(data);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('not active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but how will find when user exist from app ?

Comment: In that case you can try checking for :
$( window ).unload(function() {
 // write the same code here
});